# "Not-Noun"s: Neologism or not?

Tags: nouns, negation, neologisms

From the title, you can tell that I don't actually know what this phenomenon is called, if it has a name at all, nor if it has already existed for a long time. My own searching has been unhelpful, for this reason.

Essentially, it's when one refers to something as "not-X", in order to draw attention to a *similarity* to X while *not being* X, usually in a derogatory manner.

Examples include:

A character going to an alien planet in a cartoon, and the aliens there have "*not-cats*" and "*not-dogs*".

After the popularization of the game "Dark Souls", many "souls-like" games were created, much in the same way an explosion of first-person-shooters appeared after Doom. These games could be (and occasionally are) referred to as "Definitely Not Dark Souls" or *Not-Dark Souls* the same way fps games were called "Doom-clones".

Some believe that the band The Monkees were created to capitalize on the success of The Beatles, and called them *The Not-Beatles* or *Not-The Beatles* (source, my mother).

**Is this technically correct grammar? Does this have a name? And how old is this sort of phrase?** I find myself saying things like this often, and my meaning is always understood, so it must not be entirely new. However, it does *feel* recent, as unscientific as that sounds.

For another amusing example: the google results for "*Not-Mario*" will return several listings for Nintendo products, including Mario branded things, as expected... but then the Wikipedia page for Luigi. Because he's *Not-Mario*.

Comment: It would improve the question if you provided more specific examples of the phenomenon, with actual sentences indicating context and usage (don't just say "google it"). It's possible to guess what you're talking about, but you'll get better answers if people are sure they understand what you're discussing. Being grammatical isn't really the property of a word, but a sentence.

Comment: Noted, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you referring to  two-word constructions such as *That is a Not Mario* or *Not-Mario* with a hyphen? If the latter, can you please supply URLs where the hyphen appears--I'm having difficulty finding these. I see only instances that are separate words.

Comment: @DjinTonic Referring to both. The search engine I am using (Google) seems to interpret the hyphen as analogous to a regular space, even when using quotation marks "not-(example)" in order to force specificity. That is unfortunately making it more difficult than it ought to be for me to provide a decent linked source.

Comment: @916 Yes, Google Books also fails to recognize the hyphen even when the phrase is in quotes. However, I'm not seeing hyphens on the pages that do turn up. I don't doubt  the "Not" when we speak--I'm just not sure how we write it.

Comment: @DjinTonic Indeed. The hyphenated version may very well be just a quirk of my family / friend group / geographical location.

Comment: @916 Fear not, yours is not the only family with quirks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED has examples going back to the late 16th century, both with hyphen and as two separate words (the examples I give here are with the hyphen). It seems to have been common in situations where we might use the prefix "non-" or other methods of negation: "For *not-payment* of ministeris stipendis." (1590) "The eater despised the *not-eater*; and the not-eater iudged the eater." (1622) "If both the Beheaded and the *Not-worshippers* of the Beast were of the same kind." (1680)

There aren't many 18th century examples, but we also find the Victorians at it: "What He attributes to idols, i.e. *not-gods*." (1860) "A complete idea of a closed figure, and of the boundary which incloses it—the outline separating object from *not-object*." (1867)

It's hard to be certain whether the OED's examples reflect genuine patterns of usage, but they also have several from the 1990s which might indicate a new burst of popularity (as well as changing patterns of how they collect usage examples): "It would differ from..matter because of its immobility. It would be almost a *not-being*." (1995) "If he's including himself among the *not-movers* and *not-shakers*, socially unconscious, and poorly educated, why should anyone vote for him?" (Usenet, 1992)

You might surmise an increased popularity of "not" since the 1990s is connected with the film ''Wayne's World'' (which popularised "not" as a stand-alone negation) or computing, both of which the OED mentions. But it is an old way of forming a negative, which has persisted on and off for over 400 years.

Reference: "not, adv., n., and int." OED Online. Oxford University Press, June 2021. Web. 23 August 2021.

Comment: Sufficient, thorough, and fascinating. In the time away from this page, I have tested this question on several people of different age groups. Like this answer, it does not seem to have a specific name to anyone I asked. Did you find any specific name in your research? I have yet to accumulate enough discussion social credit to boost your response in the appropriate manner (upvote, no comment), but know that I am almost completely satisfied with the answer.

Comment: This could be a total memory fabrication, but I seem to recall there being a cartoon strip character in the early years of the 20th century who was somewhat reknowned for just using ***"Not!"***. It would have been my grandmother's "era".

Comment: The early uses with biblical associations may have derived from the translation of personal names from Hebrew to English in the Old Testament - in particular in the book of Hosea, where for example the prophet named his own children Lo-ammi and Lo-ruhamah, literally "not my people" and "not pitied" (i.e "not God's people" and "not pitied by God").

Answer (score 4):

Dropping the 'technical' as being ill-defined, 'Is this acceptable?' (correct morphology) is hard enough to address.

'It has been done for certain words in the past' does not guarantee that there is a universally productive rule. And neither does increased employment by SF writers and film-makers (and logicians).

As always, clarity is paramount. In a superb scene from 'Sherlock', Molly Hooper begged of Mycroft "How did Sherlock recognise [the body of a young woman on the slab] from ... *not* her face?"

Less transparent, but still reasonably clear,'Not the Nine O'Clock News', a British television sketch comedy show, was broadcast on BBC2 from 1979 to 1982 for those wishing for an alternative to what was probably  BBC's flagship programme at the time.

At a maths education development meeting I once attended, someone gave voice to a common concern that too many SMP GCSE investigations involved the triangle numbers. He continued "We're trying for one involving the set {2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16 ...} – '*not the triangle numbers*'."

But as always with negation, scope for ambiguity will arise with some examples. When the inimitablt *Richard* (DI Poole) (Ben Miller) was replaced as the lead in 'Death in Paradise', I'm afraid I didn't assimilate his replacement's name (*Humphrey*) for years (I stopped watching), so on the odd occasion my wife mentioned the character I used '*not Richard*'. And the next replacement was '*not not Richard*' (until I discovered Jack Mooney was very entertaining). But this would obviously be unacceptable in general conversation.

So the answer on acceptability has to be: *reasonable if used with care, in fact often quirky / witty*. I'd add: probably better avoided in formal contexts.

Stuart has probably given the best shot at earliest use (though an accurate date will be impossible to find). I'm unaware of aprecise term; *litotes* requires irony, which is obviously not always the case here: 'not-payment' is unmarked for irony.